# issue in resolving dependencies in gradle custom plugin

Tags: gradle-plugin

I developed one utility in maven.That maven utility i want to use in gradle and maven custom plugins with maven custom plugin this utility is working fine but in case of gradle plugin it is throwing following issue.

Exception is:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':hiveUnitTask'. at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)


Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.LogDivertAppender.setWriter(Ljava/io/Writer;)V
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.LogDivertAppender.<init>(LogDivertAppender.java:166)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.OperationManager.initOperationLogCapture(OperationManager.java:85)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.OperationManager.init(OperationManager.java:63)
```

Gradle plugin is developed in java.

Pom file of my utility is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.datametica.hiveunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>hive_unit</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>HiveUnit</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <hadoop.version>2.2.0</hadoop.version>
        <hive.version>1.2.1</hive.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit-addons</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-addons</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-minicluster</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-service</artifactId>
            <version>${hive.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${hive.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>hive-service</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
</plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove  log4j-over-slf4j from your class path.

Comment: Hi alex,I tried removing log4j-over-slf4j dependency but facing same issue no luck could you please help to figure out issue

Answer (score 0):

I copied class from the package of hive service jar's source code in which this error is coming and placed it in my plugin project by making same package structure as it was in hive service jar,this solved my issue I know its know perfect solution but its workaround that solved my purpose